# When closed subsets have finitely many connected componenets

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be topological space such that every its closed subset has finitely many connected componenets. Is there any charactrization for such topological space?

Comment: Please edit to correct to "closed subsets" and "finitely" (each both in the title and text) and also correct to "components" in the title and "characterization" in the text and "spaces" for the last word (also "every its closed subset" should be "all its closed subsets").

Comment: Please edit once more to get "components" in both the title and text and "characterization" in the text, and change "such that every its closed subset has" to either "such that all its closed subsets have" or "in which every closed subset has".

Comment: If $X$ is Hausdorff, it must be finite.  The non-Hausdorff case seems difficult to completely characterize.